# How to convert Int to int in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable called number of type Int

```
var number = value!.integerValue as Int
```

Now I have to create a NSNumber object using that value.

I am trying to use this constructor

```
value = NSNumber(int: number)
```

, but it does not work.

It expect the primitive type int, not Int I guess.

Anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just do `value = number`

As you can see in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

the native swift number types generally bridge directly to `NSNumber`.

```
Numbers

Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as Int and Float, to NSNumber. This bridging lets you create an NSNumber from one of these types:

SWIFT

let n = 42
let m: NSNumber = n
It also allows you to pass a value of type Int, for example, to an argument expecting an NSNumber. Note that because NSNumber can contain a variety of different types, you cannot pass it to something expecting an Int value.

All of the following types are automatically bridged to NSNumber:

Int
UInt
Float
Double
Bool
```

**Swift 3 update**

In Swift 3, this bridging conversion is no longer automatic and you have to cast it explicitly like this:

```
let n = 42
let m: NSNumber = n as NSNumber
```

Comment: On Ubuntu Linux, with Swift 3.0.2, this bridging doesn't occur. The prior two lines of code give `error: repl.swift:3:19: error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to specified type 'NSNumber'`

Comment: @ChrisPrince In Swift 3 this bridging is no longer automatic. You have to cast to an `NSNumber` by adding `as NSNumber` in the assignment. Adding it to my answer.

Comment: Hmmm. I think there is a difference in Foundation on MacOS and Linux in this regard. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828307/numeric-types-dont-automatically-bridge-to-nsnumber-in-pure-swift-on-ubuntu-lin

Comment: `NSNumber(value:1)`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because in ObjC, an `int` is a 32 bit number, and an `integer` or `NSInteger` is a 64 bit number.

```
var number = value!.integerValue as Int
```

Number is of type `Int` which corresponds to the ObjC type `NSInteger`

You now try to create with this:

```
value = NSNumber(int: number)
```

Which takes an `Int32` or `int` type, thus resulting in failure.  You have a few options that will work.

One:

```
value = NSNumber(int: Int32(number))
```

Two (probably better):

```
value = NSNumber(integer: number)
```

Three (probably best):

As @Dima points out, you can just set it directly because swift automatically converts:

```
value = number
```

Comment: The first option you mentioned is wrong, I tried that before asking the question here. NSNumber initializer only expect primitive values. Thanks though.

Comment: Never mind, I just tried Int instead of Int32, that's why I got error. My bad!

Comment: Happens! :) -- I'm gonna remove my comments since we figured it out

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3 you must use:

```
var convertedNumber = NSNumber(value: numberToConvert)
```