# Numeric types don't automatically bridge to NSNumber in pure Swift on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, server-side-swift

On MacOS, if you do:

```
import Foundation
let x = Int32(1) as? NSNumber
```

x is non-nil.

On Ubuntu Linux, if you do the same (even with Swift 3.1.1), x is nil.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a fact of a lack of bridging of numeric types to NSNumber with the Foundation with Swift on Ubuntu/Linux?

See also [Is it possible to replicate Swifts automatic numeric value bridging to Foundation (NSNumber) for (U)Int8/16/32/64 types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893517/is-it-possible-to-replicate-swifts-automatic-numeric-value-bridging-to-foundatio)
and https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/745

Comment: In https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md it says: *"We do not have bridging on Linux ..."*

Comment: Paste that in as an answer please @MartinR -- it should be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic bridging to `NSNumber` on Linux. Source:
[NSNumber bridging and Numeric types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md):

> **Considerations for Linux platforms**
>
> We do not have bridging on Linux so the `as?` cast is less important; but if it were to have bridging this would be the desired functionality.

Comment: And it looks like we'll have this in Swift 4. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/commit/101d0f6c20fc9d8c3139cc84ac54990790809b2a